# LINQ to MySQL query returns no result

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use LINQ to query a MySQL database.

First of all, I have installed the MySQL .NET connector. Then in Visual Studio I create a new Console Application.

Then I click on `Data` in the toolbar and click on `Add New Data Source`.

In the Data Source Configuration Wizard I select `Database => Dataset => New Connection`, I configure my connection parameters, I then select my relevant tables, views etc and hit Finish.

My data source is named `Foo`, the table I want to query is named `Bar`.

I then try and query my data table using LINQ like below:

```
fooDataSet.barDataTable foobar = new fooDataSet.barDataTable();
var results = from data in foobar
              select data;

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
};
```

I'm assuming that this is the equivalent to the following MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM BAR;
```

Even though my table (bar) has plenty of data in it, I don't get any data back. When I breakpoint appropriately, and drill down into the Results View of my results variable, it just saysЖ

> Enumeration Yielded No Results

[image]

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: There must be something wrong with yr datasource

Comment: If you break point the Console.Write and look at results you should be able to look at the actual SQL that is being used. Might be worth checking that there isn't any thing odd going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by repeating the initial steps on a Windows form, dragging the table I want to query from Server explorer onto the Windows Form and then analysing the code.

It turns out I needed first to create an instance of my dataset (Foo), then create a TableAdapter instance for my table (Bar).

Once I have done this, I call the `Fill` method of my table adapter, passing in the table name in the data set using dot notation.

I then run the AsEnumerable() extension method of GetData() of my table adapter to get an EnumerableRowCollection, which I can then run queries against using LINQ. My code is below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    fooDataSet fooDataSet = new fooDataSet();
    fooDataSetTableAdapters.barTableAdapter barTableAdapter = new fooDataSetTableAdapters.barTableAdapter();

    barTableAdapter.Fill(fooDataSet.bar);

    var myDataTable = barTableAdapter.GetData().AsEnumerable();

    var bnl = from results in myDataTable
              select results;

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Side note, on the XSD file created by Visual Studio, every field in every table is set by default to throw an exception if you try to apply criteria to a column with any null values. You need to change the NullValue property of the field in the XSD to either (Empty) or (Null) to avoid this.

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a new table and then trying to read data from it (there's nothing in it, its new!)

In LINQ to SQL you would do this:

```
var results = from data in fooDataset.bar 
              select data; 

foreach (var result in results) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(result); 
}
```